# i have been on this question for quaring the document for two days straight, and it is not working. don't want to cheat, can you point the problem

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

I am not able to debug what is going on. The code seems correct yet I am new to pointers to pointers, and here there are 4 in series.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX_CHARACTERS 1005
#define MAX_PARAGRAPHS 5

char *kth_word_in_mth_sentence_of_nth_paragraph(char ****document, int k, int m, int n) {
    return *(*(*(document + n - 1) + m - 1) + k - 1);
}

char **kth_sentence_in_mth_paragraph(char ****document, int k, int m) { 
    return (*(*(document + m - 1) + k - 1));
}

char ***kth_paragraph(char ****document, int k) {
    return *(document + k - 1);
}

char ****get_document(char *text) {
    /* allocating memory */
    int len = strlen(text);
    /* allocate memory for each component first */
    char ****document = malloc(sizeof(char ***));
    char ***paragraph = malloc(sizeof(char **));
    char **sentence = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    char *word = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
    /* connect all the components to point in the sequence that is required */
    *document = paragraph;
    *paragraph = sentence;
    *sentence = word;
    /* declare some numbers as iterators for the words, sentences,etc. */
    int parano = 0;
    int sentno = 0;
    int wordno = 0;
    int charno = 0;
    /* now iterate over the text filling and expanding the document at the same time */
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* feeding data in those spaces */
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (text[i] == ' ') {
            /* wrapping the current word, that is, resizing to len + 1 */
            char *current_word = *(*(*(document + parano) + sentno) + wordno);
            current_word = realloc(current_word, strlen(current_word) + 1);
            /*  resizing the current sentence to add another word*/
            char **current_sentence = (*(*(document + parano) + sentno));
            current_sentence = realloc(current_sentence, sizeof(char *) * (wordno + 2));
            
            wordno++;
            charno = 0;
            /* allocating space to that new char * / word that has been created in the same sentence */
            *(*(*(document + parano) + sentno) + wordno) = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
        }
        else if (text[i] == '.') {
            /* wrapping of the current word has to be done anyways */
            char *current_word1 = *(*(*(document + parano) + sentno) + wordno);
            current_word1 = realloc(current_word1, strlen(current_word1) + 1);
            charno = 0;
            
            if (text[i + 1] != '\n') {
                /* the paragraph does not change, and the sentence ends */
                /* resize that paragraph for adding another sentence */
                char ***current_para = *(document + parano);
                current_para = realloc(current_para, sizeof(char **) * (sentno + 2));
                sentno++;
                wordno = 0;
                /* allocating word to that sentence */
                *(*(document + parano) + sentno) = malloc(sizeof(char *));
                /* allocating space for that word */
                *(*(*(document + parano) + sentno) + wordno) = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
            } else {
                /*  if this is the last sentence of this paragraph*/
                wordno = 0;
                charno = 0;
                sentno = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (text[i] == '\n') {
            /* paragraph has changed */
            /* add another paragraph to the document */
            document = realloc(document, sizeof(char ***) * (parano + 2));
            parano++;
            /* add sentence to that paragraph */
            (*(document + parano) ) = malloc(sizeof(char **));
            /* add a word to that paragrapgh */
            (*(*(document + parano) + sentno)) = malloc(sizeof(char *));
            /* allocate space for that word */
            *(*(*(document + parano) + sentno) + wordno) = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
        } else {
            scanf("%c", *(*(*(document + parano) + sentno) + wordno) + charno);
            printf("%c\n", **(*(*(document + parano) + sentno) + wordno) + charno);
            charno++;
        }
    }
    return document;
}

char *get_input_text() {    
    int paragraph_count;
    scanf("%d", &paragraph_count);

    char p[MAX_PARAGRAPHS][MAX_CHARACTERS], doc[MAX_CHARACTERS];
    memset(doc, 0, sizeof(doc));
    getchar();
    for (int i = 0; i < paragraph_count; i++) {
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", p[i]);
        strcat(doc, p[i]);
        if (i != paragraph_count - 1)
            strcat(doc, "\n");
    }

    char *returnDoc = (char *)malloc((strlen(doc)+1) * (sizeof(char)));
    strcpy(returnDoc, doc);
    return returnDoc;
}

void print_word(char *word) {
    printf("%s", word);
}

void print_sentence(char **sentence) {
    int word_count;
    scanf("%d", &word_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < word_count; i++) {
        printf("%s", sentence[i]);
        if (i != word_count - 1)
            printf(" ");
    }
} 

void print_paragraph(char ***paragraph) {
    int sentence_count;
    scanf("%d", &sentence_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence_count; i++) {
        print_sentence(*(paragraph + i));
        printf(".");
    }
}

int main() {
    char *text = get_input_text();
    char ****document = get_document(text);

    int q;
    scanf("%d", &q);

    while (q--) {
        int type;
        scanf("%d", &type);

        if (type == 3) {
            int k, m, n;
            scanf("%d %d %d", &k, &m, &n);
            char *word = kth_word_in_mth_sentence_of_nth_paragraph(document, k, m, n);
            print_word(word);
        }
        else if (type == 2) {
            int k, m;
            scanf("%d %d", &k, &m);
            char **sentence = kth_sentence_in_mth_paragraph(document, k, m);
            print_sentence(sentence);
        } else {
            int k;
            scanf("%d", &k);
            char ***paragraph = kth_paragraph(document, k);
            print_paragraph(paragraph);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }     
}
```

this is one of the questions on Hackerrank for the C language.
link to the question
[hacker rank question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/querying-the-document/problem?isFullScreen=true)
[my profile](https://www.hackerrank.com/gautamsahil1947)

shows **aborted, `realloc` invalid size**. I couldn't find anything for the last 2 days.

*inputs for the problem*

```
2
Learning C is fun.
Learning pointers is more fun.It is good to have pointers.
3
1 2
2
5
6
2 1 1
4
3 1 1 1
```

*expected output*

```
Learning pointers is more fun.It is good to have pointers.
Learning C is fun
Learning
```

Comment: What's the input that triggers the error?

Comment: Why do you need *4* levels of indirection?

Comment: If you don't handle return values from functions that can fail (malloc, scanf, realloc) then you wasting your and our time.

Comment: `x = realloc(x, ...)` is unsafe; you need to assign it to a temporary variable, check if it's null and only then set x.  Otherwise you leak x on failure.

Comment: will try it for sure. let me see.

Comment: Minor issue but strlen() returns a size_t not an int.

Comment: it is showing realloc invalid next size

Comment: @SahilGautam If that answer was for me (use @ user name so we can tell) then I expected you to edit your question to include whatever input is required to reproduce the error.  Don't supply new data in comments.

Comment: ```realloc(): invalid next size
Reading symbols from Solution...done.
[New LWP 2783821]
Core was generated by `./Solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f03b30547bb in ?? ()```

Comment: Edit the question to include the error messages verbatim. Compile it with -g3 and run it under valgrind or debugger. It will show you where the problem is.

Comment: @AllanWind i have included the link to the problem down below

Comment: @SahilGautam I am not going to follow an external link then try to guess which of the sample inputs you used.  Edit question with the input *you* used.

Comment: `*(*(*(document + parano) + sentno) + wordno) = ...`?!?  You're *learning* C and you're starting off with **that**?!?!  Start with something simpler.

Comment: @AndrewHenle i thought of creating a basic hirerchy and later adding according to the spaces or . or \n resp. this approach was the best one i could think of in terms of memory usage and structuring the document

Comment: Good job on updating the question with the information requested.  My advise would be separate i/o from the processing.  It's odd that your print_ functions reads input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When processing regular characters (final else clause) you read additional input instead of operating over `text`, i.e. instead of:

```
                scanf("%c", &document[parano][sentno][wordno][charno]);
                printf("%c\n", document[parano][sentno][wordno][charno]);
                charno++;
```

you want to do:

```
                document[parano][sentno][wordno][charno++] = text[i];
```

By the time we hit `text[i] == ' '` for the first time the value of `***document` is "3\n1 2\n2\n" but you wanted it to be "Learning".

2. (not fixed) When processing a word (`text[i] == ' ') you expand current word, yet, you hard-code 1000 when you allocate it initially so this doesn't make sense.  Be consistent.
3. `parano`, `sentno`, `wordno`, `charno` is indices but same suggest they are counts.  It's not wrong just confusing and why you have to `wordno + 2` when relloc'ing.
4. Terminate words with `\0'.
5. When you process ' ' you add another word which you may or may not need which is fine.  But when process a '.' you look ahead to the following letter is a `\n` or not.  Be consistent.  If you look ahead then you need to check that `i + 1 < len`, and it's fragile, say, there is a stray space before the `\n`.
6. (not fixed) Memory leaks.  As the size of the sub-elements (paragraph, sentences and words) are private implementation details of `get_document()` you will have refactor the code to make those available.  I suggest:

```
struct document {
   char ****document;
   size_t paragraphs;
   size_t sentences;
   size_t words;
}
```

7. (not fixed) Deduplicate.  Similar to the print functions, create a allocation function per type.
8. (not fixed, really) `get_input_text()`.  You split the into paragraphs then concatenate everything again into a local variable then copy it into a dynamically allocated variable:

```
   char *str = malloc(BUFFER_LEN);
   for(size_t i = 0, l = 0; l < lines && i + 1 < BUFFER_LEN; i += strlen(str + i)) {
       int rv = fgets(str + i, BUFFER_LEN - i, stdin);
       if(!rv) {
          // handle error
          break;
       }
   }
   return s;
```

9. (not fixed) Separate i/o from processing.  This simplifies testing and it makes it easier to figure out what is going on.  In `main(), you read a query type then 1 to 3 numbers.`  scanf()` tells you how many items where read so you simply do.  As you don't use the kth_ functions for anything else just combine then with print_ funci

```
    int n = scanf("%d %d %d %d", &type, &p, &s, &w);
    switch(type) {
        case 1:
            if(n != 2) {
              // handle error
            }
            print_paragraph(document, p);
            break;
        ...
    }
```

10. (not fixed) Add error checks for the remaining`malloc()`, `strdup()` etc.
11. Don't hard-code magic values (1000).  I introduced the constant `WORD_LEN` but you also have MAX_CHARACTERS which is kinda the same thing.
12. (not fixed) Consider using `char *s = strpbrk(text + i, " .\n")` to copy a word at a time.  It will simplify `\0` handling, and likely to be faster than walking the `text` a byte at a time, i.e. `i += s - text + i`, just handle the `s == NULL` special case.

valgrind is now happy other than leaks (see above):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_CHARACTERS 1005
#define MAX_PARAGRAPHS 5
#define WORD_LEN 1000

char *kth_word_in_mth_sentence_of_nth_paragraph(char ****document, int p, int s, int w) {
    return document[p - 1][s - 1][w - 1];
}

char **kth_sentence_in_mth_paragraph(char ****document, int p, int s) {
    return document[p - 1][s - 1];
}

char ***kth_paragraph(char ****document, int p) {
    return document[p - 1];
}

char ****get_document(char* text) {
    char ****document = malloc(sizeof ***document);
    *document = malloc(sizeof **document);
    **document = malloc(sizeof *document);
    ***document = malloc(WORD_LEN);

    /*  declare some numbers as iterators for the words, sentences,etc.*/
    int parano = 0;
    int sentno = 0;
    int wordno = 0;
    int charno = 0;
    /*  now iterate over the text filling and expanding the document at the same time*/
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  feading data in those spaces*/
    size_t len = strlen(text);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        switch(text[i]) {
            case ' ': {
                document[parano][sentno][wordno][charno] = '\0';

                wordno++;
                char **words = realloc(
                    document[parano][sentno],
                    (wordno + 1) * sizeof *document[parano][sentno]
                );
                if(!words) {
                    printf("realloc of words failed\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                document[parano][sentno] = words;
                document[parano][sentno][wordno] = malloc(WORD_LEN);
                charno = 0;
                break;
            }
            case '.': {
                document[parano][sentno][wordno][charno] = '\0';

                sentno++;
                char ***sentences = realloc(
                    document[parano],
                    (sentno + 1) * sizeof *document[parano]
                );
                if(!sentences) {
                    printf("realloc of sentences failed\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                document[parano] = sentences;
                document[parano][sentno] = malloc(sizeof **document);
                wordno = 0;
                document[parano][sentno][wordno] = malloc(WORD_LEN);
                charno = 0;
                break;
            }
            case '\n': {
                document[parano][sentno][wordno][charno] = '\0';

                parano++;
                char ****paragraphs = realloc(
                    document,
                    (parano + 1) * sizeof *document
                );
                if(!paragraphs) {
                    printf("realloc of paragraphs failed\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                document = paragraphs;
                document[parano] = malloc(sizeof ***document);
                sentno = 0;
                document[parano][sentno] = malloc(sizeof **document);
                wordno = 0;
                document[parano][sentno][wordno] = malloc(WORD_LEN);
                charno = 0;
                break;
            }
            default: // character
                document[parano][sentno][wordno][charno++] = text[i];
        }
    }
    return document;
}

char *get_input_text() {
    int paragraph_count;
    scanf("%d", &paragraph_count);
    char p[MAX_PARAGRAPHS][MAX_CHARACTERS];
    char doc[MAX_CHARACTERS];
    memset(doc, 0, sizeof doc);
    getchar();
    for (int i = 0; i < paragraph_count; i++) {
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", p[i]);
        strcat(doc, p[i]);
        if (i != paragraph_count - 1)
            strcat(doc, "\n");
    }
    return strdup(doc);
}

void print_word(char *word) {
    printf("%s", word);
}

void print_sentence(char **sentence) {
    int word_count;
    scanf("%d", &word_count);
    for(int i = 0; i < word_count; i++){
        print_word(sentence[i]);
        if(i + 1 != word_count)
            printf(" ");
    }
}

void print_paragraph(char ***paragraph) {
    int sentence_count;
    scanf("%d", &sentence_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence_count; i++) {
        print_sentence(paragraph[i]);
        printf(".");
    }
}

int main() {
    char *text = get_input_text();
    char ****document = get_document(text);
    int q;
    scanf("%d", &q);
    while (q--) {
        int type;
        scanf("%d", &type);
        switch(type) {
            case 1: {
                int p;
                scanf("%d", &p);
                print_paragraph(kth_paragraph(document, p));
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                int p, s;
                scanf("%d %d", &p, &s);
                print_sentence(kth_sentence_in_mth_paragraph(document, p, s));
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                int p, s, w;
                scanf("%d %d %d", &p, &s, &w);
                print_word(kth_word_in_mth_sentence_of_nth_paragraph(document, p, s, w));
                break;
            }
            default:
                printf("error\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(text);
}
```

Output as expected:

```
Learning pointers is more fun.It is good to have pointers.
Learning C is fun
Learning
```

Btw, a whole different way of solving this is problem is keep the original input (`text`) then write functions to directly extract a paragraph, sentence or word from that string.  If you input is huge then create an index, say, (`paragraph`, `sentence`, `word`) to `&text[i]`.

Comment: the question is solved. thanks a lot for the hand-holding support. i did note the errors, but didn't see the solution. now know or think that i know, how pointers and memory allocation works. also learned a lot about how to debug. using vscode, found out that the previous code was confused in what or how to handle the ending paragraph which didn't have any `\n` at the end of it. also the termination is about placing the `\0` character and not resizing the array.

Answer (score 0):

finally did it.
a big thanks to @allanwind for your support

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<assert.h>
#define MAX_CHARACTERS 1005
#define MAX_PARAGRAPHS 5

char *kth_word_in_mth_sentence_of_nth_paragraph(char ****document, int k, int m, int n) {
    return *(*(*(document + n - 1) + m - 1) + k - 1);
}

char **kth_sentence_in_mth_paragraph(char ****document, int k, int m) { 
    return (*(*(document + m - 1) + k - 1));
}

char ***kth_paragraph(char ****document, int k) {
    return *(document + k - 1);
}

char ****get_document(char *a) 
{
    int len = strlen(a);
    char ****document = malloc(sizeof(char ***) * MAX_PARAGRAPHS);
    int parano = 0;
    char ***paragraph = malloc(sizeof(char **) * MAX_CHARACTERS);
    int sentno = 0;
    char **sentence = malloc(sizeof( char *) * MAX_CHARACTERS);
    int wordno = 0;
    char *word = malloc(sizeof(char ) * MAX_CHARACTERS);
    int charno = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        /*  after this way, try to learn switch conditionals*/
        if (a[i] == ' ')
        {
            /*  if find a space, that is there are more words within the same sentence*/
            /*  close the word*/
            word[charno] = '\0';
            /*  add the word to the sentence*/
            sentence[wordno] = word;
            wordno++;
            charno = 0;
            /*  create another word*/
            char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_CHARACTERS);
            /*  if the word got space without errors,*/
            if (tmp != NULL)
            {
                word = tmp;
            }
        }
        else if (a[i] == '.')
        {
            // terminate the word
            word[charno] = '\0';
            // add word to the sentence
            sentence[wordno] = word;
            wordno = 0;
            charno = 0;
            //  add sentence to paragraph
            paragraph[sentno] = sentence; 
               
            if (i != len - 1)
            {
                sentno++;
                // allocate space for new sentence, as it is not the end
                char **tmp1 = malloc(sizeof(char *) * MAX_CHARACTERS);
                if (tmp1 != NULL)
                {
                    sentence = tmp1;
                }
                // allocate space for new word
                char *tmp2 = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_CHARACTERS);
                if (tmp2 != NULL)
                {
                    word = tmp2;
                }
                
            }
            else  
            {
                document[parano] = paragraph;
            }
        }
        else if (a[i] == '\n')
        {
            // add paragraph to the document
            document[parano] = paragraph;
            parano++;
            // allocate memory for another paragraph
            char ***tmp3 = malloc(sizeof(char **) * MAX_CHARACTERS);
            if (tmp3 != NULL)
            {
                paragraph = tmp3;
            }
            charno = 0;
            wordno = 0;
            sentno = 0;
        }
        else  
        {
            /*  step 1 read the text into the word char by char*/
            word[charno] = a[i];
            charno++;
        }
    }
    
    return document;
}

char* get_input_text() {    
    int paragraph_count;
    scanf("%d", &paragraph_count);

    char p[MAX_PARAGRAPHS][MAX_CHARACTERS], doc[MAX_CHARACTERS];
    memset(doc, 0, sizeof(doc));
    getchar();
    for (int i = 0; i < paragraph_count; i++) {
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", p[i]);
        strcat(doc, p[i]);
        if (i != paragraph_count - 1)
            strcat(doc, "\n");
    }

    char* returnDoc = (char*)malloc((strlen (doc)+1) * (sizeof(char)));
    strcpy(returnDoc, doc);
    return returnDoc;
}

void print_word(char* word) {
    printf("%s", word);
}

void print_sentence(char** sentence) {
    int word_count;
    scanf("%d", &word_count);
    for(int i = 0; i < word_count; i++){
        printf("%s", sentence[i]);
        if( i != word_count - 1)
            printf(" ");
    }
} 

void print_paragraph(char*** paragraph) {
    int sentence_count;
    scanf("%d", &sentence_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence_count; i++) {
        print_sentence(*(paragraph + i));
        printf(".");
    }
}

int main() 
{
    char* text = get_input_text();
    char**** document = get_document(text);

    int q;
    scanf("%d", &q);

    while (q--) {
        int type;
        scanf("%d", &type);

        if (type == 3){
            int k, m, n;
            scanf("%d %d %d", &k, &m, &n);
            char* word = kth_word_in_mth_sentence_of_nth_paragraph(document, k, m, n);
            print_word(word);
        }

        else if (type == 2){
            int k, m;
            scanf("%d %d", &k, &m);
            char** sentence = kth_sentence_in_mth_paragraph(document, k, m);
            print_sentence(sentence);
        }

        else{
            int k;
            scanf("%d", &k);
            char*** paragraph = kth_paragraph(document, k);
            print_paragraph(paragraph);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }     
}
```